EOT,ETX in base64 encoded bouncy castle signature
I have a function that uses Bouncy Castle libraries (version bouncy castle: jdk15on-1.57 and java 8) to sign a string and return the base64 value of the signed string (including the content of the string).
Part of the code:
        String stringMessage = "exampleContentBlaBla";

            // Load the keystore
            KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
           
            keystore.load(new FileInputStream("path/to/keystore.jks"), "keystorePassword".toCharArray());

            // Get the private key and certificate
            String alias = "yourAlias";
            PrivateKey privateKey = (PrivateKey) keystore.getKey(alias, "keyPassword".toCharArray());
            Certificate certificate = keystore.getCertificate(alias);

            // Initialize CMS components
            CMSSignedDataGenerator generator = new CMSSignedDataGenerator();
            CMSTypedData content = new CMSProcessableByteArray(stringMessage.getBytes("UTF-8"));

            // Create a JcaSimpleSignerInfoGeneratorBuilder and configure the signer
            JcaContentSignerBuilder contentSignerBuilder = new JcaContentSignerBuilder("SHA256withRSA");
            ContentSigner contentSigner = contentSignerBuilder.build(privateKey);

            JcaSignerInfoGeneratorBuilder builder = new JcaSignerInfoGeneratorBuilder(
                    new JcaDigestCalculatorProviderBuilder().setProvider("BC").build());
            generator.addSignerInfoGenerator(builder.build(contentSigner, certificate));

            // Generate the signed data
            CMSSignedData signedData = generator.generate(content, true);

            // Encode the signed data to Base64
            byte[] pkcs7Bytes = signedData.getEncoded();
            String encodedData = new String(Base64.encode(pkcs7Bytes), "UTF-8");

However, when I decode the result, the string contains random characters like EOT, ETX, and x82, making it impossible to interpret the content of the signed string, even though the signature verification passes successfully.
Example:
outcome of base64 decoded signature
    String testDecoded = new String(Base64.decode(encodedString.getBytes("UTF-8")));
                    System.out.println(testDecoded );

This way I see the decoded message in the console.
And I  also used notepad++ tool for decoding for better  visualization
I have pinpointed that the EOT and ETX characters are randomly added after the signature. I tried base64 encoding and decoding the string without the signature, and there were no issues.
I have explicitly added UTF-8 encoding wherever possible. Something happens during the signing process, but I can't find a logical explanation or how to fix it.
Can anyone help me understand what is happening and how to resolve this issue?

getEncoded()  will return ASN.1 formatted data. It won't be a "simple plain text string". So to interpret it you should parse it using a ASN.1 capable tool. What result do you expect that method to return?

And with this? encodedData = java.util.Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString( pkcs7Bytes);

What I expect is the content of the content (stringMessage) not to be with EOT,ETX characters on places when the original content doesn't have them.
String encodedData = new String(Base64.encode(pkcs7Bytes), "UTF-8");
When i decode encodedData (in code or in notepad++) I can see the signature and the content. The content contains random ETX,EOT characters.
I have noticed that those ETX,EOT characters are added at every 1004 character in the decoded message ... so it is some kind of pattern I assume.

Did you try the code I gave you?

@g00se i have tried java encoders as well, it is the same

My guess is that EOT,ETX are added when BouncyCastle classes are constructing the signature along with the content, I tried looking at the source code but can't find an obvious reason.
I tried upgrading to a newer version of BC but it is not compatible with my project, so that is not an option :\

it is the same. Not possible: byte ETX = 0x03;byte EOT = 0x04;byte[] a = { ETX, EOT };System.out.println(java.util.Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(a));

What, exactly, is Base64.encode?  Where does that Base64 class come from?  It clearly is not java.util.Base64.  Using a third-party replacement of a thoroughly tested and documented Java SE functionality is never a good idea.

@VGR it is from the BC library.

@g00se I will try again with java.util.Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(a)

@g00se  I tried again  with java.util.Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(a), the content contains the EOT,ETX.
I inspected the byte stream before encoding and it contains the EOT, ETX in the middle of the content in couple of places.. so it is something added during the signing process with the BC libs but I can't figure out what.

What is pkcs7Bytes.length?

@g00se it is 7499 for the specific example i am testing but it will vary

OK. Suffice to say that any Base64 encoding that leaves non-printing characters in its output is fundamentally broken

(Except perhaps for newlines)

@g00se do you mean that even tho the EOT,ETX are in the byte stream they should be Ignored when base64 encoding is performed?

No, they should be encoded. Essentially that's what Base64 encoding is for - to turn unprintable bytes into printable text.

The base64 works ok, the issue with added EOT,ETX is in the signing process within the BC libs, when they attach the content to be signed within the signature

I was addressing the narrow issue of base64 encoding. Someone who understands CMSSignedData will need to put you right on some conceptual issues I expect. And that's probably already happened here to some extent

I am curious how you are decoding the result.  Consider editing your question and showing us the code that does the decoding.

@VGR I added a brief example, I tried encoding/decoding with BC libs and java base64  respectfully.

“I have explicitly added UTF-8 encoding wherever possible.”  Except here:  String testDecoded = new String(Base64.decode(encodedString.getBytes("UTF-8")));  Your new String does not specify a charset.  And it pretty much can’t.  Unlike in C, a String in Java is never an appropriate or safe way to store arbitrary bytes.  You probably should not be trying to print those decoded bytes as a String anyway, unless you know for certain that the original message bytes represented human-readable text.

@VGR my mistake, I did add after. I am printing for debugging purposes, because part of that decoded message contains human readable text, that is the content that is being signed in the first place.

I've been debugging the Bouncy Castle classes and pinpointed where the issue lies.
The EOT and ETX characters were added after this line:
// Encode the signed data to Base64
byte[] pkcs7Bytes = signedData.getEncoded();

The fix was to explicitly define the encoding as "DL" or "DER".
 byte[] pkcs7Bytes = signedData.getEncoded("DL");

Possible encodings you can use here are "BER", "DL", or "DER".
By default, "DER" should be used, but if it's not specified, EOT and ETX characters are added.
Site that helped me during the research: A Layman's Guide to a Subset of ASN.1, BER, and DER
Note that I have upgraded the BC version to 18on-1.78.1, so I am not sure if the mentioned fix would work for lower versions, that should be tested additionally.
